# Why ITfoxtec enforcing the logout request to be signed?

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are using the ITfoxtec.Identity.SAML2 library. Recently i encountered one problem and problem is that this library enforcing the logout request to be signed.
See below code. documentValidationResult set to NotPresent. still I am getting signaure not valid error.
[image]
In logout request assertionelement will always be null.

Can u make it correct @anders

Answer (score 0):

The SAML 2.0 standard requires logout request to be signed. Therefore, the ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 library also ophold this requirement.

Yes the assertion element is always null in logout request.